# Comparing timestamps in different formats in R

Tags: r, time, compare

I have two timestamps

```
 a<-"2016-11-24 08:30:00"
 b<-"31Jul2016 21:26:00"
```

I want to compare which timestamp is earlier.  How can I do that? How can I make sure the timestamps are in the same format so that they are comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strptime`to covert you character to date:

```
a <- "2016-11-24 08:30:00"
b <- "31Jul2016 21:26:00"

aa <- strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
bb <- strptime(b, "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Then you can check which timestamp is earlier.

```
> aa < xx
[1] FALSE

> aa > xx
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime` library to compare date-time in different formats. It converts them into `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` class so that it is easy to compare them.

```
library(anytime)
anytime(a) > anytime(b)
#[1] TRUE
```

where,

```
anytime(a)
#[1] "2016-11-24 08:30:00 IST"
anytime(b)
#[1] "2016-07-31 21:26:00 IST"
```